# Facebook Open Graph Not Pulling Specified Open Graph Properties

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

Is there a trick to getting facebook to pull your open graph information when someone likes me on my site?

I have specified this on the page:

```
 <link rel="canonical" href="my site name"/>
 <meta property='og:locale' content='en_US'/>
 <meta property='og:type' content='article'/>
 <meta property='og:title' content='My custom title'/>
 <meta property='og:description' content='my customer description'/>
 <meta property='og:url' content='my url'/>
 <meta property='og:site_name' content='my site name'/>
 <meta property='og:image' content='my custom image'/>
```

However, when I like the page, it post the web pages actual title and an image that appears on the webpage, instead of the custom page title that I have in my og:title and my custom image I have in my og:image.  Any help you can provide is much appreciated.

Comment: what does [Facebook's Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook caches data for the page for about 12-24 hours. It can be updated by using Facebook's Debug Tool (as Igy points). Could it be the case? Did you try Tool after changing your og data?